# Fill container with 3 boxes, 2 square and 1 16:9 and keep aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect

I'm struggling with a responsive design where the container should be filled with with boxes with 3 boxes on each row. 
2 square and 1 16:9, all three with the same height (so the 4th box should also automatically be the 1st on next row) with 5px space in between.

Felt simple at start but I can not find an easy way how to make this work!?
Any ideas!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the 16:9 box you can establish the height through padding. This works because padding-top and padding-bottom are established by the width of an element.

```
div.sixteen_nine_box{
  height:0;
  /* 9 / 16 = 56.25 */
  padding-top: 56.25%;

}
```

So what's happening here is that dependent on the width allotted to your box (the context, your row) the height will always be 56.25%, or 9/16ths of the width.

Now to ensure the same height of all three elements per row you should note that the rectangle will be 7/16ths wider (43.75%) than each box. So if the width of the rectangle is the 16 from 16:9, the boxes are 9 in width. Making a total width of all three 34 units (16 + 9 + 9).  So that leaves the widths (+margin if you're including any) for each element is as such:

--Rectangle: 16/34 = 47.05% of total row

--Square: 9/34 = 26.47% of total row

--Square: 9/34 = 26.47% of total row

Alternatively, for a more prebuilt solution. You can use [boostrap embed classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/). You don't have to embed media in them, they will retain aspect ratios with text, other elements, etc.

Comment: With that said, i'm not sure what you were hoping to put in your 16:9 box. As padding constituting the height may require a workaround depending on what's inside of it.An image could be placed as the background of the box though, or the entirety used a button, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I try your example using the percentage for the widths and it looks ok but using padding-top that way width 56.25% seem to get 56.25% of the page height and not the element?!

.cell-16-9{
    width:47.05%; 
    height:0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }

Comment: You may want to place each row in some sort of container element. You don't necessarily need to specify the width of the rectangle. Assuming two squares, a rectangle with 16:9 and of the same height as the squares should automatically take up about 47%

Comment: Using bootstrap or a grid system you can get the functionality you want (where the rectangle bumps down to the next row predictably). Or juts making your own row element can roughly set the height of all three elements.

Comment: Bootstrap also has an embed class that retains aspect ratios. If that's of interest I included the link in the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

If the container has full window width, you can use `calc` and the `vw` unit like in my first snippet below: I calculated that the widths have to be in a proportion 9 / 16 / 9 with the sum being the container width, and subtracting 10px for the 2 time 5px margin, so for the square the width would be `calc((100vw - 10px)/34*9)`, for the 16:9 rectangle it's `calc((100vw - 10px)/34*16)`. The 34 equals 9+16+9. The height has to equal the width of the squares.

NOTE: Please open the snippet in full window mode - for some reason it won't work in the default snippet window.

As I wrote, this version only works for the full window since it uses `vw`, not for any container which is less wide than the window.

In other containers (i.e. less wide than the window) the *width* calulations can be done similarly using percentages for the proportions in relation to the overall width of the container. For the heights you have to use Javascript in that case, simply setting the heights to the generated width of the squares. I added a second version/snippet below demonstrating that which should work in *any* parent container.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc((100vw - 10px)/34*9);
  height: calc((100vw - 10px)/34*9);
}

.middle_16_9 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: calc((100vw - 10px)/34*16);
  height: calc((100vw - 10px)/34*9);
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="middle_16_9"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Here's the version using percentage calculation on the widths and jQuery on the heights:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var squarewidth = $('.square').outerWidth();
      $('.square').css('height', squarewidth);
      $('.middle_16_9').css('height', squarewidth);
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc((100% - 10px)/34*9);
  height: 100px;
  /* will be changed immediately by script */
}

.middle_16_9 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: calc((100% - 10px)/34*16);
  height: 100px;
  /* will be changed immediately by script */
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="middle_16_9"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```